# Password strength check in PHP

Tags: php, validation, passwords

I am trying to create a password check script. I already have checks for email (for not allowed characters) like this:

```
  public function checkEmail($email)
  {
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
      return true;
    else
      return false;   
  }
```

So I am looking for a password validation function that checks passwords have at least one alphanumeric character, and one numeric character, and a minimum of 8 characters, and also provides error messages.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the specific problem you are labouring under?

Comment: `strlen()` is the best strength check. Cumbersome passwords [aren't worth it](http://xkcd.com/936/).

Comment: You can reduce your function to `return !!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);`

Comment: @Treffynnon Nothing usefull so far ... strlen() will replace the characters not check them?

Comment: No, strlen() simply checks the length of a string

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
public function checkPassword($pwd, &$errors) {
    $errors_init = $errors;

    if (strlen($pwd) < 8) {
        $errors[] = "Password too short!";
    }

    if (!preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $pwd)) {
        $errors[] = "Password must include at least one number!";
    }

    if (!preg_match("#[a-zA-Z]+#", $pwd)) {
        $errors[] = "Password must include at least one letter!";
    }     

    return ($errors == $errors_init);
}
```

*Edited version of this: http://www.cafewebmaster.com/check-password-strength-safety-php-and-regex*

Comment: I think you should have [a-zA-Z] in last, right? And actually Byakugan's definition to last one alphanumeric, but I think he ment 1 alpha, 1 number, strlen>=8 (which you have done here, except that A-z).

Comment: if there's an error you can return a JSON object, describing the error in code and message, like:  return json_encode(array("ok"=>1,"msg"=>"length<8 chars"));

Comment: @Byakugan - Use a second parameter passed by-reference, so the function can put the message there if necessary. That's more robust than using the return value for boolean or for a string (error message).

Comment: Fixed a-zA-Z and added error messages the way martinstoeckli suggested.

Comment: @Jeroen - Because you don't know, what `$errors` contains when passed to the function, you should initialize it with null. Otherwise it's well done.

Comment: Fixed, but instead of setting it to `null`, I save its initial value and compare it at the end - this way it gets combined with errors from other code if necessary.