# Validate password with regular expression on php

Tags: php, regex

I am not clear with regular expression of php. I would like to validate password with below rules:

- Password contain at least 8 characters
- Password contain at least 1 letter
- Password contain at least 1 digit

Could anyone help me?

Comment: You could write out those conditions explicitly without using a regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

```
public function checkPassword($pwd, &$errors) {
$errors_init = $errors;

   if (strlen($pwd) < 8) {
      $errors[] = "Password too short!";
   }

   if (!preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $pwd)) {
      $errors[] = "Password must include at least one number!";
   }

   if (!preg_match("#[a-zA-Z]+#", $pwd)) {
      $errors[] = "Password must include at least one letter!";
   }     

   return ($errors == $errors_init);
}
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10753064/1676962

Answer (score 2):

You could use this regex :

```
preg_match('/(^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}$)/i', $password);
```

Details :

- `(?=.*\d)` : at least one digit
- `(?=.*[a-z])` : at least one letter
- `.{8,}` : 8 or more characters
- `/i` : case insensitive regex

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 0):

this is the regex :

```
^((?=.*\w)|(?=.*\d])).{8,}$
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/iU4mH1

Comment: This will match `11111111`, but there's not a single letter. (same for `aaaaaaaa`)

Comment: You misunderstand `\w`