# I want to make my password to contain lowercase, uppercase, 8 characters and a character

Tags: php, authentication, passwords, character

I want to make my password to contain lowercase, uppercase, 8 characters and a character.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'baza');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Your account has been created succesfully! <a href="login.html"> Click here </a> to login.';
$value  = $_POST['name'];
$value2 = $_POST['surename'];
$value3 = $_POST['genre'];
$value4 = $_POST['numrikarteles'];
$value5 = $_POST['email'];
$value6 = $_POST['username'];
$value7 = $_POST['password'];
if (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/', $value7) || strlen($value7) < 8) {
    echo "Invalid password!";
} //- kushti per ta kontrollu passwordin 
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (name, surename, genre, numrikarteles, email, username,password) VALUES ('$value', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$value5', '$value6', '$value7')";
if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Password strength check in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752862/password-strength-check-in-php)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Please format your question, this is unreadable.

Comment: I tried helping you by formatting the code, but it's not possible as it has random words through it. Please take the time to find out how to post questions as people here do want to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict user to enter minimum 8 character password which will contain upper and lower case letter and one special character you can use regular expression like

```
^((?=(?:.*[a-zA-Z]){7})(?=(?:.*[@#$%^?])).{8})$
```

Comment: Okay, where exactly to write this code in my code up there?

Comment: you can use this expression in your if condition for checking the string format